# How do I define my own custom SQL Aggregate Function?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, aggregate-functions

I'd like to use `GROUP BY` and select a value based on my own aggregate function similar to `MIN`,`MAX`, etc.

For example, given the data below, I'd like to group by `id` and get `X` availability if any values in the `GROUP BY` are `X`, otherwise return `?` if it is contained... etc.

```
+------------+--------------+------+
| date       | availability | id   |
+------------+--------------+------+
| 2015-09-08 | Y            |    1 |
| 2015-09-07 | Y            |    1 |
| 2015-09-06 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-05 |              |    1 |
| 2015-09-04 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-04 | Y            |    2 |
| 2015-09-05 | Y            |    2 |
| 2015-09-06 | Y            |    2 |
| 2015-09-07 | Y            |    2 |
| 2015-09-08 | Y            |    2 |
| 2015-09-09 | ?            |    2 |
+------------+--------------+------+
```

`SELECT * FROM availability GROUP BY ID [....]`

Desired Output:

```
+------------+--------------+------+
| date       | availability | id   |
+------------+--------------+------+
| 2015-09-08 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-04 | ?            |    2 |
+------------+--------------+------+
```

Comment: [Like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx) - although you can probably do what you want with `count`/`sum` and `case`..

Comment: Do you have to reference an assembly? Can you just define what you want with a SQL Function?

Comment: That depends entirely on the database, which you have not specified.

Comment: I wasn't aware this issue wasn't covered in basic SQL commonalities. 

I'm using Microsoft's Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when availability = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'X'
             else '?'
        end)
from availability a
group by id;
```

Your question doesn't specify where the date comes from, so I've left it out.

Comment: That's a clever solution.  Is it limited to a binary selection? It seems to me that it can't be extended to `n` classifications.

Comment: @CodeOcelot . . . You would have to specify the rules for the combination.  However, that would be a different question, so ask a new question.